# Bring openCV window to front with focus on macOS

Tags: python, opencv, window, focus, topmost

How to bring an openCV window to foreground with focus?

http://www.noah.org/wiki/OpenCV_display_window_on_top_with_focus doesn't do anything.

This achieves Topmost, but not Focus:

```
cv2.imshow('foo', my_2d_numpy_array)
cv2.setWindowProperty('foo', cv2.WND_PROP_TOPMOST, 1)
```

I'm on macOS.

Answer (score 2):

You can install `pyobjc`, `import AppKit` and then use the following line before `waitKey()`:

```py
AppKit.NSApplication.sharedApplication().activateIgnoringOtherApps_(1)
```

Comment: Works for me, it both brings the window to front and it gets focus.